# Namespace for global variables

Tags: c++, namespaces, sdl, global, sdl-2

I have variables I want accessible to all of my application. Is this bad practice? If so, why?

```
namespace Global
{
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    UI* new_view;
}
```

**Another suggestion:**

How about passing a pointer to the global variables to classes in the constructor and keeping it as a local variable?

```
class A
{
    SDL_Renderer* m_renderer;

    A(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
} 

A::A(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    m_renderer = renderer;
}
```

Comment: why don't you pass the variables _explicitly_ to functions or whatever class that uses those variables?

Comment: That's what I've done so far, but it leads to functions having 9+ arguments. I added another suggestion in my question.

Comment: if you are always passing all three, then you can define a `struct` which includes the three as memebers, and pass only one struct

Comment: @user3720733: And if you´re not always passing them together...well, nothing evil in using 9 parameters. :p

Comment: Don't think of them as globals; think of them as program member variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this bad practice?

Yes it's bad practice to use global variables, no matter if these are placed into a separate namespace or not.

> If so, why?

It introduces uneccessary dependencies amongst a system's modules. Keep data and behavior localized to classes, that are responsible to do specific things.
There are rare cases where singletons make sense, but then these aren't supposed to be simply global variables, but have a static member (or free) function to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it´s bad.
Good part: You worked around the first badness reason (cluttering the global namespace),
but don´t name your own namepace "Global". Pick something more unique.
Bad part: There are more things, like creating unwanted dependencies
(like program part A won´t work if part B doesn´t modify the values)